# swiper.js content misplaced when keyboard appears on android webview

Tags: javascript, css, web, webview, swiper.js

`swiper.js` content misplaced when keyboard appears on android webview.
[this is page 2,the icons are misplace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPuVN.jpg)
I have try use `min-height` to fix, but it didnt work, and I want to know how to fix or how I can know the layout of the web on wechat app

Comment: bty i use vertical model